# Store Exchange Rates date wise in Database (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I need to implement a database table where a batch job will call external APIs to get the exchange rates for the day and store the data in  a matrix format. As the base currency to be used for getting the exchange rate may differ from one merchant to another,  I need to have the ability to provide the rates using any base currency at a given point of time. Imagine the table like this matrix below -

[image]

Options are -

1. Use PostgreSQL and have fixed columns for each currency which would mean more than 100 columns (there are 180 in world)considering all major currencies and equal number of rows everyday.
2. Use some Non SQL database like MongoDB and store as hashmap

My question is what's the best possible way of storing exchange rates in database in a way that I can provide the exchange rate for currenct day based on any base currency provided by the user ?

Comment: Your table with 100 columns violates normalization rules. You just need a table with four columns: the date, the source currency, the target currency and the exchange rate.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: I have one more query regarding the API which gets the exchange rates. If I need to have exchange rates for every currency as base currency do I have to call the API once for each currency ? Is it a good idea to store exchange rates for only one base currency and make it a two step conversion when e.g the base currency is USD and I need to convert SAR to INR (Step-1 convert SAR to USD Step-2 Convert USD to INR) ? Is there a possibility to loose precision during the process ?